# Revert Alt+Tab to switch between applications only

Tags: 16.04, unity, shortcut-keys, application-switcher

In Ubuntu 14.04, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> would always switch to different a application. This seems to no longer be the default in 16.04.

The behavior was that if:

- I have multiple **terminal** windows open
- focus on one terminal window
- and **firefox** open

Then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> would always switch to firefox. I would like revert to this behavior.

Comment: What does it do now?

Comment: @George If the focus was previously in one of the terminal windows, it will switch to that instead.

Comment: After pressing Alt+Tab keep holding the Alt key down and a pop-up menu allows you to switch windows groups and if a group has more than one window sub-groups within it.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour has not changed. I keep on using it to move about applications. The only time where this changes is if you have your applications in different desktops, then you have to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>.